# How to properly Adjust CoreUI sidebar width in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, sidebar, core-ui

I try to change CoreUI sidebar width. But it in coreui document does not specify how to change it.

I try to manually add css style to Vuejs component but it does not work out.

// Here is the code from coreui proejct

import {   Sidebar as AppSidebar  } from '@coreui/vue'

```
  <AppSidebar fixed>
    <SidebarHeader/>
    <SidebarForm/>
    <SidebarNav :navItems="nav"></SidebarNav>
    <SidebarFooter/>
    <SidebarMinimizer/>
  </AppSidebar>
```

[image]

I hope anyone can provide me answer to this issue. Thank you very much

Answer (score 8):

If you're using SCSS, then override the following variables in your `_variables.scss` with your preferred width size. For example following code sets sidebar to 250px wide. Navbar brand width is set slightly shorter so as to take care of menu button.

```
// Variable overrides
$navbar-brand-width:                  205px !default;
$sidebar-width:                       250px !default;
```

Answer (score 2):

For sidebar width in coreui you can overwrite $sidebar-width scss variable in _variables.scss file

```
// Variable overrides

$sidebar-width: 300px;
```